# Orientability of $ x(u,v)= \bigg(\bigg(1+v\cos\frac{u}{2}\bigg)\cos(u), \bigg(1+v\cos\frac{u}{2}\bigg)\sin u, v\sin\frac{u}{2}\bigg) $

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, orientation

Consider the map:
\begin{equation}
x: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}: (u,v) \rightarrow \bigg(\bigg(1+v\cos\frac{u}{2}\bigg)\cos(u), \bigg(1+v\cos\frac{u}{2}\bigg)\sin u, v\sin\frac{u}{2}\bigg) \end{equation}
There is given that , for $\epsilon$ sufficient small, $M_{\epsilon}=x(\mathbb{R}\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon))$ is a surface.

My question: Is $M$ orientable and how does $M$ look like?

Approach: I have to check that there is an differentiable unit normal vectorfield that is defined on whole $M$. I first started calculating $\dfrac{x_u\times x_v}{\|x_u\times x_v\|}$, but the result was very complicated. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can check via Implicit Function Theorem that the image $M$ of $x$ is a differentiable surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and therefore it is locally orientable!

After, you can note that $M$ is the Möbius strip ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Geometry_and_topology)); in particular, $M$ is diffeomorphic to the algebraic surface
\begin{equation}
\left\{(x,y,u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^4\mid\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2=1\\
(u^2-v^2)y=2uvx
\end{cases}\right\}
\end{equation}
e via Jacobian matrix, you can prove that $M$ is not orientable!